# overlay video above image using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

if i want overlay video above video i use the following

```
 'ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4-i image.jpg -filter_complex "[1]scale=300:300[i1];[0][i1]overlay=100:100" -acodec copy -preset ultrafast -qscale 0 outPutPath.mp4';
```

it work correctly

but if i want to overlay video above image like following

```
 'ffmpeg -y -i image.jpg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[1]scale=300:300[i1];[0][i1]overlay=100:100" -acodec copy -preset ultrafast -qscale 0 outPutPath.mp4';
```

it execute the command successful without any errors message
but when i run the video it does not work with the following error message by my player

```
MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/mp4v-es, null, 2626042, null, [750, 579, 25.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES, null, null)
```

any help ?

Comment: You encoded with an option that's not supported by whatever the "MediaCodecVideoRenderer" is (Android?). You're not providing enough info for anyone to diagnose your issue here. But, I'd try `-pix_fmt yuv420p` output option first.

Comment: yes android . so can you please help me with full command .. at least i will try . i don't know why there no too mush of people could help of that type of ffmpeg tag . i feel alone